# Dynamically updated list in Rcpp stores only last value

Tags: r, list, loops, rcpp

I have a NumericMatrix whose values are updated every iteration of a loop. I want to store the matrix in a List every iteration. The code below gives a minimal reproducible example. However, when I compile and run this in R, every element of the list is identical to the final matrix, rather than storing each matrix. Why would this be the case, and how can I fix it? This seems like a very simple problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Example code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List updatingList(int n) {
  // Create a NumericMatrix that will be updated every step
  NumericMatrix mat(n, 2);
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++) { // set the initial state of the susceptible hosts
    mat(i,0) = 0; // initial Th1 
    mat(i,1) = 1; // initial Th2
  }
  // create a List that will store mat every step
  List list(n);
  
  for (int j=0; j < n; j++) {
    // store the value of mat
    list(j) = mat;
    // update mat
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) { 
      mat(i,0) += 1; 
      mat(i,1) += 1; 
    }
  }
  return(list);  
}

/*** R
updatingList(3)
*/
```

Example output:

```
> updatingList(3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    3    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    3    4

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    3    4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few years with R you become familiar with the 'copy-on-write' idiom.  What you have here is, really, just *one* instance of the matrix so what you back is consequently always the same.  As it is the same matrix.  And that is, come to think (a bit) about it, a *feature*.

What you want here is so 'seal' the matrix value away. So all we need to change is one line:

```
    // store a deep copy of mat
    list(j) = clone(mat);
```

By requesting deep copies at each loop run you actually get *distinct* instances as you desire.

##### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("answer.cpp")

> updatingList(3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    2    3

>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! That actually rings a bell regarding how things are stored in C++. I assume the issue was that I'm pointing each element of the list to the same position in memory, and then the loop updates the matrix that is stored in that position. Regardless, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: The one abstraction I find helps is that each R type 'internally' is 'simply a `SEXP`' or pointer to an S expression (which is a union/variant type).  The pointer part is key.  Once you view that way you realize you stored pointers to a matrix you altered so all return elements shared content _because of the common pointer_.